# Several keys dont work on ASUS laptop keyboard

Tags: laptop, keyboard

Keys [Spacebar, e, Caps Lock, 3, Enter(on num pad)] stopped working.

Opened laptop few days ago just to clean it and it worked fine but two days after, those keys stopped responding after I came home and turned on the laptop.

I decided to open laptop again and reconnected keyboard to motherboard. Turned on the laptop and it didn't work. After browsing for 5 minutes they just started working. I was relieved and rebooted. They stopped working again.

Those keys don't respond in Windows 10, Ubuntu and grub.

USB keyboard work perfectly.

Comment: Sounds like the keyboard connector cable is damaged ...

Comment: I had an ASUS and when booted into WIndows certain keys would not be recognized.  If I booted to Linux the keys were recognized.  As @DavidPostill stated it was my keyboard connecter.  Replacing that resolved my issue.

Comment: @user2676140 So you replaced your laptop keyboard?

Comment: @SHK - I replaced the connector cable itself.  Once you remove the keyboard you will see the cable connecting it to the motherboard.  It may not look worn or frayed but that would be the 1st thing I would replace.